# Как спарсить все .txt файлы в большом кол-ве папок?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система, txt

Нужно в 10.000 (+-) папках найти все .txt файлы с ключевым словом внутри них (к примеру, "doma").

Пути к этим .txt могут быть разными, и в каждой папке несколько таких файлов.

Пробовал через `import glob, os` сделать - хотя бы начать - но не то. Очень прошу помочь, если не кодом, то хотя бы понятным для новичка объяснением, что мне надо прочитать и узнать чтобы это сделать?

Comment: Но учтите, что если это вдруг Windows, то папки с числом объектов в тысячи и десятки тысяч могут обрабатываться довольно медленно, так уж устроена файловая система. Если в каталоге будет порядка 20 000 файлов/папок, изрядные тормоза неминуемы.

Comment: @CrazyElf - А, кстати, на C# есть соответствующий enumerable - объект, что означает, что даже папки с десяткми миллионов файлов начинают обрабатываться сразу. Правда, если спросить, сколько в такой папке файлов - вот тогда, скорее всего, немного потормозит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью os.walk():

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.txt' and 'doma' in os.path.splitext(f)[0]:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, f)
            print(full_path)
```

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта!

Comment: @S.H. можно короче?

Comment: Нет, я мысленно прикинул, как бы это было на C#, потом посмотрел на пайтон - и захлебнулся слюнями...

Comment: @S.H. на то он и "высокоуровневый язык" ;)

Comment: Правда, в Вашем решении отсутствует проверка на то, что в найденном файле есть ключевое слово "doma" - ну, как автор вопроса спрашивал...

Comment: @S.H. добавил, спасибо!

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответ, скоро буду проверять и отпишу !

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться [Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods):

```
from pathlib import Path

start_dir = Path("/")

res = [str(f) for f in start_dir.glob("**/*doma*.txt")]
```

если искать нужно всегда с корня, то решение можно немного сократить:

```
from pathlib import Path

res = [str(f) for f in Path("/").glob("**/*doma*.txt")]
```